# Spamassassin blacklist_to testing

Tags: configuration, spamassasin

I have some rules in my local.cfg file with some addresses defined as `blacklist_to`.  However, I keep getting spam for these addresses -- or rather any email whatsoever.

How can I test spamassassin to see why it keeps accepting said emails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can feed an arbitrary message to spamassassin by piping it to `spamc -R`.  You'll get a spamassassin report on your message that looks like

```
1.5/5.0
1.5 : -0.0 NO_RELAYS              Informational: message was not relayed via SMTP
 0.1 MISSING_MID            Missing Message-Id: header
-0.0 NO_RECEIVED            Informational: message has no Received headers
 1.4 MISSING_DATE           Missing Date: header
```

The first line is the score of the message and the threshold score for messages to be considered spam.

Comment: Do you not mean `spamassassin -D -t < msg`? In any case, there is no mention of `blacklist_to` in the debug information.

Comment: I use `spamc` because it's shorter to type :) but you do need the `spamc` package installed.

Comment: Still does not answer the fact that there is no `blacklist_to` debug information.